# How to find namespace, url, method and action from wsdl

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am new to android trying to develop a mini project. The project needs to validate the clients login from webservice that i have created in java (netbeans).

The problem is on the statement in android where i write:

```
SoapObject request=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
```

the application crashes(force close).

I doubt that I don't know where to get the namespace url and the method name from.

Comment: post your entire code and logcat

Comment: Would you please show us the wsdl?

Comment: cant post full wsdl but main portion are: <definitions targetNamespace="http://ymapps/" name="loginvalidateService"> − <types> − <xsd:schema> <xsd:import namespace="http://ymapps/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/webservice1eg/loginvalidateService?xsd=1"/> </xsd:schema> </types>                                                             <service name="loginvalidateService">
−
<port name="loginvalidatePort" binding="tns:loginvalidatePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/webservice1eg/loginvalidateService"/>
</port>
</service>

Comment: namespace is prefixed by http://

Answer (score 4, accepted):

targetNamespace="**ymapps/**" should be your **NAMESPACE**,

Have a look at [Understanding WSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx). and [A WSDL Example](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/WWW/webservices/wsdlexample.html)

Comment: THANKS amy got the solution the error was a stupid one. didnt write the exact field name from database when was adding arguments in soap request. The field name should have been the same as in the database on webserver

Answer (score 1):

in php u can get it like this :

```
    $client = new SoapClient("http://my_exposed_url?wsdl");
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());    
    var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

Answer (score 0):

NAMESPACE is like this:

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://package1.your_app.org/";
```

where your web service is organized in packages: org/your_app/package1/ServiceClass.java

METHOD NAME is like this:

```
private static String METHOD_NAME = "methodName";
```

Take a look at this:
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/Links

Comment: thanks @enrmarc but its not working buddy. tried all the permutations and combinations but didnt find any luck.

Comment: my webservice is running in netbeans and its working. Plz tell me where can i find these namespace, action, url and all that from there or wsdl. because i require them when accessing from android.